# how to use variable in path firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

```
let variable = "-KyCVrQ3WnarYdl6u9cp"
this.db.list('/data/{{variable}}').remove();
```

How do i use variables in path ?

i tried

```
{variable}
[variable]
${variable}
```

couldnt make it work.

thanks

Comment: To use string interpolation, use backticks: ``list(`/data/{{variable}}`)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
this.db.list('/data/'+variable).remove();
```